# Why does exporting to Unity WebGL change the speed of objects in my game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, webgl, game-physics

**GOAL**
So I have a space-invaders type game I have made to practise unity and I want to upload it to Itch.io as I have done in the past.
[This](https://youtu.be/PtdsKFxs-BA) is a clip of the game.
I switched platforms to WebGL in Build Settings etc, and everything worked fine in Unity.

**PROBLEM**
However when I built it and uploaded the zip file to Itch.io, [the aliens are now a lot faster than usual](https://leowb.itch.io/aleens/). 
 *(Be aware there may be other things that have changed, I just haven't been able to get to them since it is extremely hard).*

**CODE**

*Alien movement:*

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AleenController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    public float speed = 10f;

    ScoreController scoreController;

    AudioSource aleenDie;

    void Start()
    {
        scoreController = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Score").GetComponent<ScoreController>();
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        aleenDie = GameObject.Find("Main Camera/AleenDie").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3 (0, -1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "laser")
        {
            aleenDie.Play();
            scoreController.score += 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**
I am really struggling to find out what is wrong here, since everything is fine in unity. If you do need more details just leave a comment.

Comment: Without knowing how your game is written all anyone can do is guess. We don't have any speed issues with our WebGL versions. They are the same as Android and iOS.

Comment: How are you updating their movement? Are you using delta time?

Comment: @SoDamnMetal Sorry, I have updated the question

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use physics you should

- not set or get values via `Transform` at all
- do things in `FixedUpdate`

In general though in your case instead of using

```
void Update()
{
    rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3 (0, -1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

at all simply set the velocity once like e.g.

```
void Start ()
{
    ...

    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.down * speed;
}
```

---

The rest seems to depend a bit on your screen size. Looks like you are moving your elements in pixel space -> the smaller the display the less pixel distance between the top and bottom -> the faster elements seem to travel.